# Save a PATH to a file

Tags: java, javafx

I got a simple problem, but I do not know how to solve it.
I need to save some files in a directory, but I need to save the path to it.
Because, when I restart the program, I want that my program looks the folder where I left my files, and build a TreeView in JavaFX. Like eclipse IDE does.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score -1):

You can use OS AppData folders. For example, for Windows it would be  /User/AppData/, for Linux you can use /home/{username}/.your_app_name/
Create config file, XML or any format you want.

```
String configPath = "/home/enchantinggg4/.javaFxApplication/";
File config = new File(configPath + "config.xml");
config.createNewFile();
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(config);
writer.write(....);
writer.close();
```

Then you can read it after relaunch or smf.